# Coercing an array with semver, sorting it and then reverting it to its pre-coerce counterpart

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

A problem with [`semver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver) is that its different functions return different outputs:

```js
const semver = require("semver")


semver.valid("1.0.0")
//=> "1.0.0"

semver.valid(" 1.0.0 ")
//=> null

semver.valid(" v1.0.0 ")
//=> null


semver.clean("1.0.0")
//=> "1.0.0"

semver.clean(" 1.0.0 ")
//=> "1.0.0"

semver.clean(" v1.0.0 ")
//=> null


semver.valid(semver.coerce("1.0.0"))
//=> "1.0.0"

semver.valid(semver.coerce(" 1.0.0 "))
//=> "1.0.0"

semver.valid(semver.coerce(" v1.0.0 "))
//=> "1.0.0"
```

I've got an array of versions which need to be:

1. Trimmed from spaces `" 1.0.0 " => "1.0.0"`
2. Coerced (to support parsing the most complicated version inputs)
3. Sorted using `semver.rcompare`
4. Reverted to their non-coerced counterpart unless a boolean has been specified.

Here are some test cases which need to be satisfied:

```js
convert([" 1.0.0 ", " 3.0.0aa ", " v2.0.0 ", " v0  "], false)
//=> ["3.0.0aa", "v2.0.0", "1.0.0", "v0"]

convert([" 1.0.0 ", " 3.0.0aa ", " v2.0.0 ", " v0  "], true)
//=> ["3.0.0", "2.0.0", "1.0.0", "0.0.0"]
```

I'm thinking this would be a good use case for `Map`—since it can hold 2 pairs of values so it can store the identity of the versions throughout the conversion—however, I don't have any idea how to implement this.

There's some extra conversation on [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/to-semver/issues/3) GitHub issue.

Comment: @jwdonahue This is javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best strategy here is to use a map-like array structure:

```js
const semver = require('semver')
const cleanSemver = require('clean-semver')

module.exports = (versions, clean = true) => {
    const sortedVersions = versions
        .map(version => version.trim())
        .map(version => [version, cleanSemver(version)])
        .filter(version => version[1])
        .sort((a, b) => semver.rcompare(a[1], b[1]))

    if (clean) {
        return sortedVersions.map(version => version[1])
    }

    return sortedVersions.map(([version]) => version)
};
```